# Mac - GAE: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, compilation, java

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy an AppEngine project. The error comes up when trying to compile JSPs:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.

Now, I'm on a Mac, and I've installed JDK 1.7.0-25. I also modified eclipses.ini in eclipse.app by including the -vm line:

```
openFile
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

Within Eclipse, the "Installed JREs" is also pointing to JDK 1.7.0-25.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For "Installed VM" please confirm the location is something like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home`

On OSX, I don't have any -vm entry at all and can successfully deploy AppEngine projects so don't know why that would be needed.

Try removing the JRE from your project and adding re-adding it.

Comment: Location confirmed. I originally didn't have any -vm - it gave that error. Putting in -vm apparently forces Eclipse to use a specific JDK. A JDK is required to compile JSP. But yeah, still doesn't work.

Comment: Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: @iht Try removing the JRE from your project and adding re-adding it.